# Why is PDO working without dbname?

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, database-connection

I am connecting to my database using this command:

```
$resource = new PDO('odbc:driver=FreeTDS;Server=127.0.0.1;Port=8090;UID=Reporting;PWD=readonly;');
```

There is no dbname specified, and yet, it still connects to a database. The problem is, it is connecting to the wrong database. I tried including a section `dbname=DATABASENAME;`, but this was entirely ignored. How do I tell PDO to connect to a different database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATABASE instead of DBNAME, i think this is the problem:

```
$resource = new PDO('odbc:driver=FreeTDS;Server=127.0.0.1;Port=8090;DATABASE=DATABASENAME;UID=Reporting;PWD=readonly;');
```

Comment: I have almost exactly the same problem and tried this solution but to no avail! I am going to have more than on database so I need to connect to the right database but database name DSN is being ignored completely. I have noticed that information concerning this paradox is quite scarce on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to do the Standard operation? like....

```
new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=test;",'sa','password');
```

and which database you are using? ms sql server or some else?